# How to get cumulative growth in pandas given a growth rate and special rules?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have this dataframe:

```
date    amount
2018/01 100
2018/02 105
2018/03 110.25
2018/04 200
```

As you can see, every month, the amount is increasing by 5% of the previous value. However, every the 4th month (2018/04), this rule does not apply. Instead, it should only past the constant value of 200 for example.

How do I program this in pandas dataframe?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: @Datanovice I am not sure which pandas command to use in order to construct the logic. Can you help me?

Comment: what's your starting dataframe?

Comment: @Datanovice I have only the first value in column amount given, i.e. '100'. From there, I need to continue the sequence for every month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Lroy_12374 It's not clear what would happen in month's 5-8 and beyond, which would affect how to write the logic. For example:
a) Should month 5 be 5% higher than month 3? OR
b) should it be 5% higher than every fourth month (i.e. April 2018, August 2018, December 2018, April 2019, August 2019, December 2019, etc.)? OR
c) Should it be 5% higher than Month 4 had month 4 not been a constant, which means that Month 5 is 1.05^2*(Month 3).

Also, the definition of a constant is not clear. Literally, will it be 200 or something for every fourth month? Or, will it be a different number that does not follow the pattern of the other 3 months.

I have written some code for scenario c) above:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['2018/01','2018/02','2018/03', 
'2018/04','2018/05','2018/06','2018/07', '2018/08']})
start_amount = 100
constant=200
growth=.05
df['amount'] = np.where((df.index+1)%4 != 0,
                        start_amount * (1+growth) ** df.index, constant)
df
```

The key here is to use **np.where** and implement logic based on the row number, which you can get with **df.index**. What I am doing in the code above is adding 1 to the row **(df.index+1)**, since python starts counting at 0 and you want logic based on the fourth month. Then, I am using the % symbol, which returns the remainder after dividing, which you want to equal zero if it is the fourth row (i.e. 4/4 = remainder 0). So, basically, where something is not every fourth row you want to multiply by 1.05 (5% increase) RAISED according to the row number, and where it is the fourth row you want to return a constant.

I hope this helps.

Comment: great answer, better than what i was going for

Comment: Thanks @Datanovice